# How to generate a token from a username and password in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, token

I have a login feature as follows:

```
$("#Wraper").on("click.Authenticate", '#btnLogin',btnLogin_onClick);
 btnLogin_onClick: function (event) {

                if (event)
                    event.preventDefault();
                if ($(event.currentTarget).attr('id') == "btnLogin_Mobile") {               
                    $('#txtLogin').val($('#username_mobile').val());
                    $('#txtPassword').val($('#password_mobile').val());

                }
                var username = $('#txtLogin').val(), password = $('#txtPassword').val(); // username=test password=password       
//how do i create a token here
                if (!username || !password) {
                    $("<div>Please enter user name and password</div>").dialog({
                        position: 'centre',
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: "Error",
                        buttons: { "Okay": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                    });

                    return;
                }
```

so the above gets my username and password.
How do i generate a token that encrypts  the username and password and return that token?

for example i get the following string `username=test;password=password` encrypt this string to give me the following token=`vZyQ4Ng+WElqWSkUzjqZhjGuxadZB+iUbVldtWE+2rk=`
The token is to be passed into a URL.

Comment: What "token" are you referring to here? Please give some examples to elaborate on it. Also, return the token from where (source) to where (destination)?

Comment: Is ``username`` is **UNIQUE** for every user? If yes then you can generate a hash for the ``username``. You can use ``SHA-128`` or ``SHA-256`` hashing for this. What are these tokens? Are these **tokens** ``private`` or ``public`` use?

Comment: @NotABot username is unique. the token is used to be passed in a URL so that when it goes to that URL the client can decrypt the token to find out the username and password

Comment: @marry Means from which source to the destination you are sending the token?

Comment: from the website when the user logins, then a link will be made present to the site it needs to go,so when the user clicks on the link for example https://test/auth/ auth needs to store the token and pass it

Comment: Why would you need to encrypt anything in JavaScript, assuming that your connection is HTTPS?

Comment: that was the request to be done in the website

Comment: There's [Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto), but ... It's blocked from http connections, for a good reason. If the connection is using https protocol, extra encrypting doesn't increase the security, and should not be done.